# Taylor's series and the function argument dimension

Tags: taylor-expansion, unit-of-measure

I've stumbled over an interesting question. In $\cos(x)$, $x$ is measured in, say, radians. When I expand cosine in Taylor's series, I have the terms with $x^3$, $x^5$ etc. so I am summing up $\text{rad}^3$, $\text{rad}^5$ etc. to get the dimensionless value of cosine. Obviously something is not right here.

I couldn't find any clarification on this issue, so I would appreciate some explanation. I've got one idea myself, but I am quite unsure about it:

> If $f = \cos(x)$, $x$ can be expressed as $|x|\cdot u$, where $|x|$ is the value and $u$ the unit of the argument, in our case $u = \text{rad}$. In the Taylor's expansion we have $f^{(n)}(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)^n$.
>
> $f'(x) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, unit of $\partial\cos$ is 1, since cosine is dimensionless, while the unit of $\partial x$ is radian. Thus the unit of the $n$-th derivative of cosine is $1/\text{rad}^n$.
>
> We then come to each term in the Taylor's series for cosine being dimensionless, thus resulting in the dimensionless sum.

Does it make sense?

**EDIT:**
Since the discussion in the comments has concentrated around radians being dimensionless units, please consider *any* function with any unit of the argument. The whole consideration remains the same. For example, energy can be expressed as $E=mc^2 = f(m)$. The expansion will then have the terms including $\text{kg}$, $\text{kg}^2$, $\text{kg}^3$ etc. Something should “compensate” these powerful kilograms, and I think it's $f^{(n)}$ that does. But I'd like to hear a confirmation from someone on better terms with mathematics than I am.

Comment: Radians are dimensionless. Function arguments are just (real or complex, or other) numbers (for $\cos,\,\exp$ and its ilk). But irrespective of that, yes, your argument makes sense.

Comment: To add to what Daniel said, remember that $\pi \, \text{rad}$ is the ratio of the circumference (length) to the diameter (length), so it is dimensionless.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I really have troubles with the expression "some unit is dimensionless". Anyway, you can replace cosine with any other function where $f$ and $x$ have different units.

Comment: A dimensionless unit is just a tag to indicate where a number comes from. In the case of radians, as M. Vinay said, $x$ radians is the quotient of two lengths, and $\frac{x\text{ parsec}}{1\text{ parsec}} = x$ is just a number.

Comment: I understand the argumentation but I still do not like it :) I am fully on the side of the author of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.18616). However, as said, forget the radians, take anything else, such as $E=mc^2=f(m)$. Mass is definitely not dimensionless, and neither is the energy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that the Taylor series also involves derivatives. And what is a derivative? Let us denote the units of $x$ as $[x] = \text{s}$ and $[f(x)] = \text{m}$ (You can think of time, and space, respectively).

Then a derivative is $f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$. So, plugging in the units, we get $[f'(x)] = \text{m}/\text{s}$. Similarly, $[f''(x)]=\text{m}/\text{s}^2$, and you can continue this onwards. Again, intuitively the derivative is the velocity, and the second derivative is the acceleration, so you can see that if you think of $f$ and $x$ as space/time, the units again check out.

Now, the Taylor expansion looks like this:

$$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac12f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2 + ...  \approx \text{m} + \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}} \text{s} + \frac {\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}\text{s}^2 + ... = \text{m}+\text{m}+\text{m} ... = \text{m}$$

(I have used the $\approx$ sign to transfer from precise expression to the measurement units. Hope that this is clear).

Comment: Lovely, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.